# Sky Drive Integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I need sky Drive integration in my IOS application..i.e uploading the files and photos to a sky drive account...

Can any one provide some guidelines or sample code url links...

Thanks in advance..